# LabVIEW: Whenever I convert a string to binary and try to save it, it just saves the initial string

Tags: labview

Issue occurs between "string to byte array" and "Write binary file"

[image]

I'm trying overall to make a system that takes any type of file and convert it into a string of binary numbers. However I just receive "" followed by my initial string in my binary file and leaves my "final write" file empty. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's classical race condition. Read and write operations are executing in random order. Just use error wire and connect "Close File" function from the write chain to "Open File" function from the read chain.